# PostgreSQL - finding and updating multiple records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table:

```
ID | rows | dimensions
---+------+----------- 
1  |  1   |   15 x 20
2  |  3   |   2  x 10
3  |  5   |   23 x 33
3  |  7   |   15 x 23 
4  |  2   |   12 x 32
```

And I want to have something like that:

```
ID | rows | dimensions
---+------+----------- 
1  |  1   |   15 x 20
2  |  3   |   2  x 10
3a |  5   |   23 x 33
3b |  7   |   15 x 23 
4  |  2   |   12 x 32
```

How can I find the multiple ID value to make it unique?

How can I update the parent table after?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: please ensure you correctly tag your questions. you've tagged this one with mysql, database and postgresql. The mysql tag is incorrect for sure, the generic database one probably not needed when it is tagged as postgresql since it isn't a general question but specific to postgresql.

Comment: Which parent table are you referring to? When you make the 3a and 3b to distinguish them as separate, does it matter which one you tag as "a" and which row as "b"?

Comment: I have table counts like 154 records. So I need to find duplicated records and add a letter or number to them to make it different.
The Parent table I mean, that table without letters, so without unique ID's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with stats as (
    SELECT "ID", 
           "rows",
           row_number() over (partition by "ID" order by rows) as rn,
           count(*) over (partition by "ID") as cnt
    FROM Table1
)
UPDATE Table1
   SET "ID" = CASE WHEN s.cnt > 1 THEN s."ID" || '-' || s.rn 
                   ELSE s."ID"
              END
  FROM stats s
 WHERE S."ID" = Table1."ID"
   AND S."rows" = Table1."rows"
```

> I'm assuming you cant have two rows with same `ID` and same `rows` other wise you need to include `"dimensions"` on the `WHERE` too.

In this case the output is

[image]